# Javascript proper getters

Tags: javascript

[On this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp), It says that to make properties limited to being read-only, use the `get` keyword. However I do not see the point of adding the `get lang()` function that basically returns the `language` property. I mean, yes you'd not be able to do something like `person.lang = 'whatever'`, but you *would* be able to do `person.language = 'whatever'`. How would I properly restrict that access **using getters**, not `writable: false`?

Comment: Use the MDN docs instead of w3fools for more detailed explanation. Short answer is you can't without using constraints in Object.defineProperty. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: One is through docs and convention you can use _varname to indicate that the case shouldn't be touched but used through getter property only. But if you really want to restrict then use a closure variable and provide access through getter property.

Comment: see [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't necessarily for restricting access, though they can be, but they actually run code while accessing the variable, kinda like a syntactic equivalent of `.lang()` (which I'd call a thunk)

You can prevent anyone from tampering with the variable by restricting them to 'read-only' and disabling that `writable` property in `defineProperty`.

If you remove public access to the underlying property, the instance can act as an accessor or proxy to it (the class instance could have a reference to a private scope that it was generated in, for example). In that manner, you'd never be able to write a value to the accessor's field, but you could still access the otherwise privately scoped variable.

---

If not a factory pattern like that, I could imagine defining the getter function at a later time via some third party which holds private variables. You could also pass a third party:

1. the instance
2. the data store
3. some sort of registry that can verify the instance is authenticated

This third party could connect it's getter to the otherwise private data store variable, rather than during instantiation as in a factory pattern

---

I believe privatization comes with additional layers, and the get/set thing is just syntactic

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a field private use [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

```js
class Foo {
  #language
  constructor(lang) {
    this.#language = lang;
  }
  get lang() {
    return this.#language;
  }
}

const f = new Foo('Japanese');
console.log(f.lang);
//f.#language = 'German'; // error!
```

note: private class fields are relatively new. you'll need to use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io) to support old browsers.

Comment: Probably not appropriate to say it now, but I was looking for a 'classical' explanation (with constructor functions'.

Comment: Well, the answer you checked is not `getter`. The definition of `getter` is that you use an expression like `someInstance.someField` and a function is called. If you have to put `()` at the end it's not a getter.